# Padding spilling out the bottom

Tags: css, padding

I encountered this problem when trying to apply styles to the hover state of a link.

I couldn't quite come up with the right phrase to google this problem so apologies if this is a duplicate post. I might also add that I am a complete beginner.

Anyway this is what happens:
The padding is not being applied inside the header, it is instead spilling out into the main page content.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>Header 1</h1>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: LobsterTwoBoldItalic;
    src: url(../fonts/LobsterTwo-BoldItalic.ttf);
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: LobsterTwoBoldItalic;
}

header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #3399FF;
    position: relative;
}

header h1 {
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 48px;
}

header nav {
    float: left;
}

header nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

header nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 32px;
}

header nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 20px 25px 10px 25px;
}

header nav ul li a:hover{
    background: #CCC;
    color: #217C7E;
}
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If the bottom padding on your H1 is what is spilling out, try overflow:hidden on your header element. Another option would be to put padding-bottom:20px on your header element instead of your H1.

Comment: can you show a example of how you expect it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Padding adds space to the inside of the element.**

[image]

What you want is to change it so the padding on the bottom is only 0px, this way you get the spacing you want around the text, without going past the bottom of the navigation bar.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nn4eboaf/2/)**

Simply change this part of your CSS file:

```
header nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
--> padding: 20px 25px 0px 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
header nav ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 20px 25px 10px 25px;
}
```

to

```
header nav ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 20px 25px 1px 25px;//this puts it to the bottom of the nav bar in JS fiddle
}
```

You can try it in jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/v93mzvvj/

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea, but why even have 1px on the bottom? 1px is still visible, might as well change it to 0.

Comment: I did that with the assumption that you wanted it to touch the bottom.

Comment: He does want it to touch the bottom of the navbar, but not extend beyond it. 1px extends it beyond the bottom by 1px; 0px makes it touch the bottom.

Comment: In the fiddle I set up, it didn't go over it. Either way, its either the 0 or 1 lol